# How to build a puppetserver 6 rpm package?

Tags: puppet

I have managed to build puppet-agent 6 rpm, but the puppet server use a different build system, and there is no building instruction. Anybody know how to build?

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot rely on [the RPMs from Puppet, Inc.'s official repository](https://puppet.com/docs/puppetserver/6.4/install_from_packages.html)?

Comment: I am trying to run puppet server in a aarch64 box which is not officially supported, and I have made the needed patch for that, so I need to repack the rpm to include my patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have patched the installed puppetserver, and used **rpmrebuild** to create a new rpm from the patched installation.